# waypoint Plugin Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-events

> ```
> $(function() {
>
>     // Do our DOM lookups beforehand
>     var nav_container = $(".nav-container");
>     var nav = $("nav");
>
>     nav_container.waypoint({
>         handler: function(event, direction) {
>             nav.toggleClass('sticky', direction=='down');
>
>             if (direction == 'down') nav_container.css({ 'height':nav.outerHeight() });
>             else nav_container.css({ 'height':'auto' });
>         },
>         offset: 15
>     });
>
> });
> ```

How are you? - I'm using [imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/) to move nav element down the page. How ever I will like to un-stick the nav element at a specific segment of my page and then when scrolling back up for it to stick it back and carry it to its original spot- maybe 30pixcel after scrolling down.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: -1 for your bad title.

Comment: :) looks like a spec that we need to implement.

Comment: Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why repost the [same question as ealier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891218/jquery-waypoints-plugin#comment22627625_15891218)?

Comment: So does everyone but most people ask ONCE!

Comment: yo whats your problem tonight- if you not helping just be gone!!!

Comment: Jerry, many people like me really really want to help but if you ignore advice on how to revise your text then repost the same unrevised question, you will do yourself no favours with regard to attracting willing experts.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you're wanting an element to stick when it passes a certain threshold, and return to fixed when it goes above that?

if so - check out http://drewdahlman.github.io/Pinned/ this will do exactly what you're wanting. it's an easy to use plugin.

```
$("#element").pinned({
    bounds: 30, // when to become sticky
    scrolling: 0, // position during scroll 
});
```

it will return to its original position after it's above 30 and stick when it hits 30px. Make sure you set it's default position to absolute.

Good luck!

Comment: No i'm using waypoint

Comment: any particular reason for waypoints other than your sticky element?

Comment: Basically too deep in the project Pin seems to be good too-- but too deep into the project - Any help Drew?

Comment: do you have any other dependancies on waypoints? Also your question doesn't make a lot of sense.. you're talking about sticking and unsticking but your sample code has height.... can you provide a fiddle of what you're doing?

Comment: also i see you have a class of sticky being applied? have you tried changing its position to fixed top: 0? and then when not sticky it sets to absolute and top: 30px?

Comment: Here is an Example: http://jsfiddle.net/DQgkE/1/

So what if I want the NAV stop get unstuck at Chapter 2 - and when it comes back up it will pick it up back.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27811/discussion-between-jerry-s-and-drew-dahlman)